# Adding new column based similar to a sql operation in python pandas

Tags: python, sql, csv, pandas

The sql operation is as below :

```
   UPDATE table_A s SET t.stat_fips=s.stat_fips
   WHERE t.stat_code=s.stat_code;
```

If a similar operation needs to be done on csv A comparing some value from csv B How to achieve this in Python?

Data: 
Lets assume -

```
CSV A
col1    stat_code   name
abc      WY         ABC
def      NA         DEF
ghi      AZ         GHI

CSV B
stat_fips   stat_code
2234        WY
4344        NA
4588        AZ


Resulting CSV :

col1    stat_code   name    stat_fips
abc       WY        ABC     2234
def       NA        DEF     4344
ghi       AZ        GHI     4588
```

Adding the attempted code so far :

```
    df = pd.read_csv('fin.csv',sep='\t', quotechar="'") 
    df = df.set_index('col1').stack(dropna=False).reset_index
    df1['stat_fips'] = df1['stat_code'] 
    print df1
```

(Not really sure on pandas. learning the basics yet)

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('fin.csv',sep='\t', quotechar="'")
df = df.set_index('col1').stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
df1['stat_fips'] = df1['stat_code']
print df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging your example data, this looks like merge operation on your `stat_code` column:

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame([["abc", "WY", "ABC"], ["def", "NA", "DEF"]], columns= ["col1", "stat_code", "name"])
df_b = pd.DataFrame([[2234, "WY"], [4344, "NA"]], columns=["stat_fips", "stat_code"])

merged_df = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on="stat_code", how="left")
print(merged_df)

  col1 stat_code name  stat_fips
0  abc        WY  ABC       2234
1  def        NA  DEF       4344
```

Comment: How to make sure that stat_fips remains an int instead of string?

Comment: The merge won't change your `stat_fips` from int to string so you don't need to worry about this. You might have strings for `stat_fips` already before the merge takes place.

Comment: It shows as a str type though!.. I need to do a int operation on the resulting new column in the csv and it fails.

Comment: Right, this might be the case because when loading your data via `pd.read_csv` the stat_fips column might not be typed correctly. Try to convert your stat_fips column to integer via `merged_df["stat_fips"] = merged_df["stat_fips"].astype(int)` before applying your int operation.

Comment: How to do this if there are more common rows in csv A and B

Comment: @viv Have a look [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) - you should find what you need there.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` `d`:

```
d = df2.set_index('stat_code')['stat_fips'].to_dict()
df1['stat_fips'] = df1['stat_code'].map(d)
print (df1)

  col1 stat_code name  stat_fips
0  abc        WY  ABC       2234
1  def       NaN  DEF       4344
2  ghi        AZ  GHI       4588
```

Or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='stat_code', how='left')
print (df3)

  col1 stat_code name  stat_fips
0  abc        WY  ABC       2234
1  def       NaN  DEF       4344
2  ghi        AZ  GHI       4588
```

Comment: how to change the last column type to int instead of string?

Comment: use `df3. stat_fips = df3. stat_fips.astype(int)`

Comment: ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer, previously command if I try to see the type of this column it is str. I am pretty sure

Comment: There is problem some `NaN` values, so first replace NaN to some scalar `df3.stat_fips = df3. stat_fips.fillna(0).astype(int)`